# Fastest algorithm to detect if there is negative cycle in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra, floyd-warshall, bellman-ford

I use a matrix `d` to present a graph. `d.(i).(j)` means the distance between `i` and `j`; `v` denotes the number of nodes in the graph.

It is possible that there is negative cycle in this graph.

I would like to check if a negative cycle exists. I have written something as follows from a variation of [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm):

```
let dr = Matrix.copy d in

(* part 1 *)
for i = 0 to v - 1 do
  dr.(i).(i) <- 0
done;

(* part 2 *)
try
  for k = 0 to v - 1 do
    for i = 0 to v - 1 do
      for j = 0 to v - 1 do
          let improvement = dr.(i).(k) + dr.(k).(j) in  
          if improvement < dr.(i).(j) then (
          if (i <> j) then
            dr.(i).(j) <- improvement
          else if improvement < 0 then
            raise BreakLoop )
      done
    done
  done;
  false
with 
  BreakLoop -> true
```

My questions are

1. Is the code above correct?
2. Is the `part 1` useful?

Because I call this function very often, I really want to make it as fast as possible. So my  3) question is if other algorithms (especially `Bellman-Ford`) can be quicker than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question about the correctness of your code is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

---

Either of [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) or [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is appropriate for this problem. A comparison of performance follows:

- [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) (Wikipedia)

  - Time-complexity: `O(|V|*|E|)`
  - Space-complexity: `O(|V|)`
  - [The section on "Finding negative cycles"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) is what you want
- [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) (Wikipedia)

  - Time-complexity: `O(|V|^3)`
  - Space-complexity: `O(|V|^2)`

Since `|E|` is bounded by `|V|^2`, [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) is the clear winner and is what I would advise you use.

---

If graphs *without* negative cycles is the expected normal case, it might be appropriate to do a quick check as the first step of your algorithm: does the graph contain any negative edges? If not, then it of course does not contain any negative cycles, and you have a `O(|E|)` best case algorithm for detecting the presence of any negative cycles.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... As my only representation of a graph is a matrix, the step in wiki page of Bellman-Ford `for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:` still needs to be realized by two loops `for i = 0 to v - 1 do for j = 0 to v - 1 do ...`. So for my case, `|E|` and `|V|^2` are quite same, no?

Comment: @SoftTimur Oh, I had missed the part about you using a matrix for the graph. In that case, yes, they're the same. :) With that in mind, I'd still say Bellman-Ford has a *slight* advantage, because of the lesser space-complexity, but I agree you could use either.

Comment: Bellman Ford won't detect a negative cycle if it is not reachable from the source.

Answer (score 8):

Although the options listed in [Timothy Shield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906754/9260406) are all correct algorithms for finding a negative cycle in a directed weighted graph, they are not the fastest.

My go-to algorithm in this case is always the [Shortest Path Faster Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_Path_Faster_Algorithm).

Although it has a worst-case time complexity of `O(|V|*|E|)`, which is the same as Bellman-Ford, there are very few graphs for which the SPFA actually reaches that time. In practice, it is much faster, even reaching an (unproven) average time of `O(|E|)`.

I have written an article in [my blog](https://konaeakira.github.io/posts/using-the-shortest-path-faster-algorithm-to-find-negative-cycles.html) explaining the details of using the SPFA to find negative cycles.

If you don't want to read the full article, the pseudocode you need is below.

```
function SPFA(G):
    for v in V(G):
        len[v] = 0
        dis[v] = 0
        Queue.push(v)
    while !Queue.is_empty():
        u = Queue.pop()
        for (u, v) in E(G):
            if dis[u] + w(u, v) < dis[v]:
                len[v] = len[u] + 1
                if len[v] == n:
                    return "negative cycle detected"
                dis[v] = dis[i] + w(u, v)
                if !Queue.contains(v):
                    Queue.push(v)
    return "no negative cycle detected"
```